# Adding WMS or WFS services to Google Earth Engine

Tags: wms, google-earth-engine, wfs

I'm new to using Google Earth Engine. I would like to know if data from WMS or WFS services can be added to this platform. I need this information to do a data validation

The information is on the servers:

http://idecor-ws.mapascordoba.gob.ar/geoserver/idecor/wms

http://idecor-ws.mapascordoba.gob.ar/geoserver/idecor/wfs

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no, although you can upload large "Assets" like geotiffs, shapefiles, etc. to your account.

Comment: you can do it using the python API, if you want I can show you

Comment: Yes, it would be very useful.

Comment: Could you show me as well? @LisandroAgost

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe pls show us ^^

Comment: See this guide on complex raster uploads: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_manifest

Answer (score 1):

Earth Engine is not currently able to pull data from external WMS/WFS services.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/235017)

Comment: True, amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can connect WMS to Google Earth Pro*.

Go "Add" > "image Overlay"

and then under the "Refresh" tab, you will find a button "WMS Parameters".

Add a new Server, and then use your address as posted.

*I only have GE Pro, i dont know if this functionality is limited on any other versions.